# search and get value from String

Tags: mapping, altova, map-force

AM new to altova mapforce.I need to search and get value from String.How to write user defined Function for this?

string is **abc|A,cde|B**
Input is  **abc**
need output **A**

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries , **substring-after**

Send the string as first argument and '|' as second argument